# Log all access of subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, logging

I have a directory structure like

```
/logging.php
/customer1/
/customer2/
/customer3/
...
```

Now I need to log all access of the subdirs customer1, customer2, customer3 and so on.

Can I somehow (like a htaccess rule) lead all access trough a php file logging.php which saves the access into a mysql database and than forwards to the wanted directory?

I don't want to include the logging.php in every single file of the subdirs, as the subdirs are dynamically generated.

Comment: Use Google Analytics or just pull the info out of your Apache access log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple .htaccess rule should suffice.

```
RewriteRule ^(customer\d+(/.*)?)$ /logging.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Within logging.php, just look at `$_GET['path']`

This is assuming that the directory and files in question are in the web root of your site (Usually something like `public_html/` or `wwwroot/`)